# How to run a Batch File from an SSIS Package

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

How can you run a Batch File from an SSIS Package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run any type of executable including batch files in your control flow from an Execute Process Task.

Answer (score 0):

when ever package .bat extension through packge 
dtexc Fileloaction
After Run The Package  then executed
   It is simply way to executepackage

Answer (score 0):

I had this same question, and couldn't find a good answer anywhere. There were a few more confounding factors with mine. I was trying to set up an SSIS package that runs on a server, and have it run a batch file based on results the package received from a SQL query.

To do that I had to use a *Foreach Loop Package*, and then an *Execute Process Task* within it.
Then I had to reference where the command line utility was on the server and then have my executable start with a "/c" (I started with a "/k" but that would fail all the time, truth be told I don't know what "/c" or "/k" do with CMD)

Then have my batch files be all in the *WorkingDirectory*. Then... Tada! it actually worked!